# Opposite idiom for going with the flow

Tags: idioms, american-english

According to the Cambridge dictionary, going with the flow is defined as to do what other ​people are doing or to ​agree with other ​people because it is the ​easiest thing to do.
I am writing a paper and I'm really stumped as to what would be an idiom, or a way to describe a person who is *not* [going with the flow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-with-the-flow).

Specifically, the sentence which I need this for is this:
I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences which has been a struggle for my **____________** personality.

Note: I am specifically asking about an idiom, and not words such as: inflexible, rigid, stiff, unadaptable, firm.

Comment: From the perspective of those people who *are* going with the flow, those who don't are *dragging their heels*, or *trying to turn back the tide*. From the perspective of the "lonely furrow ploughers", they're *marching to a different drum* (or *refusing to act like sheep*, or whatever).

Comment: Try *contrarian* and see if it fits your sense.  *Type A* is assertive, no matter which way the wind is blowing.

Comment: The book, *Accidental Tourist* by Anne Tyler, is about a travel writer who refuses to *go with the flow*.  He seeks out accommodations that do not jar his stay-at-home sensibilities, and do not reflect the new location in which he finds himself. He is not a *do in Rome ...* kind of person.

Comment: You might be called a rebel.  Contrarian too, but I see that applied when talking about specific things, like investing.  I wouldn't use the word contrarian to describe a person's general attitude about life.  This may be a local use thing.

Comment: *To go against the grain.*

Comment: Or "to the beat of their own drum"...

Comment: *Why* is the person not going with the flow? Is it due to independence (i.e. ignoring the flow - sometimes ending up with the flow, sometimes against), non-conformism (going against the majority, but still going with the flow of some 'non-conformist' group), or being disagreeable with everyone ('just because')? The idiom you seek might be different in each case.

Comment: I would call someone for whom it is impossible to go with the flow a stick in the mud.

Comment: This is a poorly phrased question. It asks for an idiom, but then gives an example sentence suited to an *adjective* not an *idiom*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *don't go with the flow* then you [*go your own way*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/go-one-s-way) or [*do your own thing*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-your-own-thing). Admittedly, for your sample sentence, *go-my-own-way personality* might be a bit cumbersome. So you may prefer ***independent*** or ***independent-minded***:

> [[*independent-minded* in Collins Dictionaries:]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/independently-minded) self-reliant and seeking autonomy

[***-minded*** in Cambridge Dictionaries:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minded)

> having a ​particular ​character, ​interest, or way of ​thinking about things:
>
> She's very ​[] independent-minded (= she has a very ​[] independent ​character).

So, to see how it sounds in your sample sentence:

> I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences which has been a struggle for my ***independent*** personality.
>
> I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences which has been a struggle for my ***independent-minded*** personality.

Comment: This is very good! Funny how I thought about "independent-thinker" like a second ago, but obviously "minded" is much better :)

Comment: @Idos, I considered *free-thinking*, but it's very much connected with skepticism and atheism, which doesn't look like what you're looking for.

Comment: After thinking about your question it seems more of a question of comfort.  I don't think my "rebel" comment above nor this "independent" answer here really addresses it.  To come to terms with cultural differences .... hummmm.  What do you call those who are comfortable in there own environment. Who are those uncomfortable with change?  I might be reading the question wrong but I go with something that describes set in your ways.

Answer (score 17):

How about "going against the grain"?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/against_the_grain

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, all the answers so far seem to have missed the natural opposite of [going with the flow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-with-the-flow) — [**going *against* the flow**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-against-the-flow):

> to do or say the ​opposite of what most ​people are doing or saying:
>   *With this new ​book, she is going against the flow.*

Admittedly, it's not a perfect fit for your sentence, since that context really needs an adjective to modify "personality".  Fortunately, English is flexible enough that if you want, you *can* press a verbal phrase like "going with/against the flow" into service as an adjective — possibly hyphenating it to show that you're treating it as a single unit — without the grammar screaming *too much* in pain:

> *I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences which has been a struggle for my **going-against-the-flow** personality.*

OK, so it's probably not the greatest literary masterpiece ever.  But if you really want an exact antonym for "going with the flow", then this is it.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Also, in a similar vein, I thought of **swimming upstream** (which I've now noticed was the very first answer, from [T.E.D.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/300256/91730)).

Comment: _This_ seems to be the answer to the main question. The second part of the question (`Specifically, the sentence which I need this for is this:...`) wouldn't even work well with the original `going with the flow`).

Answer (score 6):

I believe *[swimming upstream](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swim_upstream)* is about as opposite a sentiment as you can get. It even means the opposite in the two phrases' literal sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit. I don't think this will work there, right?

Comment: @Idos - It doesn't work there any worse than "going with the flow" does. I'd suggest rephrasing if you wanna use either. Both are verb phrases, and your context requires an adjective

Comment: well that is why I want the *opposite* of going with the flow...

Comment: Also I would appreciate any rephrasing suggestion

Comment: Note that you can adjectify this, albeit with somewhat awkward results: _my upstream-swimming personality_.

Comment: I've also heard "swimming against the stream" which is closer to a direct opposite, but not different enough to warrant a separate answer.  Can be accompanied by images of salmon leaping up waterfalls to their spawning grounds.

Answer (score 4):

The common idiom **[bucking the trend](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/buck-the-trend)** appears to fit your scenario:

> to be ​obviously different from the way that a ​situation is ​developing ​generally, ​especially in ​connection with ​financial ​matters

To adapt this into an adjectival form you could say you have a **trend bucking** personality or, in nounal form, that you are a **trend bucker**. Both of these words do see usage, as evidenced by [google searches](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=trend-bucking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=WoqaVv6RKsPuUKS0uYgK#q=%22trend-bucking%22) - we see that:

> Trend-bucking women are living longer

Answer (score 4):

Some words and expressions that come to mind are:

- **nonconformist**: a person who does not conform to a generally accepted pattern of thought or action ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonconformist))
- **rebellious**: refusing to obey rules or authority or to accept normal standards of behavior, dress, etc. : having or showing a tendency to rebel ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebellious))
- **marching to the beat of a different drummer**: To do things in one's own way regardless of societal norms and conventional expectations. ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/march_to_the_beat_of_a_different_drum))

If you want to go with the idiom, I suggest the following rephrasing of your sentence:

> As someone who has always marched to the beat of a different drummer, I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences. This has been a struggle for my nonconformist personality.

I also liked T.E.D.'s suggestion of **swimming upstream**, which was the first thing that came to mind when I read the title of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Consider,

***thinking-outside-the-box***

> think outside (of) the box; *also* think out of the box: to develop ideas that are different and unusual. Usage notes: sometimes used with verbs other than think: *You need to look outside the box and see what you can come up with*. Etymology: based on the idea that limiting your thoughts is like thinking inside a box which can contain only a certain number of ideas [Cambridge Divtionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Think+out+of+the+box)

***offbeat***

> : differing from the usual or expected; unconventional: *an offbeat comedian*. [Random House](http://dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/offbeat)

***out-of-the-way***

> : being out of the ordinary; unusual: *out-of-the-way memorabilia* [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/out-of-the-way)

[***off-the-beaten-path***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22off+the+beaten+path+personality%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLh6e-irHKAhVByBoKHYLoBTwQ_AUIBygA&biw=1024&bih=672&dpr=2)

> off the beaten track/(*Chiefly AmEng*) path: uncommon; out of the ordinary.

***off the wall***

> : *Slang* extremely unconventional. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+wall)

***out-in-left-field***

> left field:  a state or position far from the mainstream (as of prevailing opinion) [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/left%20field)
>
> *McCall's popularity comes from his “out in left field” personality* [MMA Corner](http://themmacorner.com/2013/07/19/mid-year-all-stars-picking-the-top-fighter-in-each-ufc-division/)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to use the phrase "going against the tide" as an adjective before the noun *personality*, if you want to retain the idiomatic meaning, i.e. doing something in opposition to the majority.

Another choice is to use word "non-conformist" before "personality". Non-conformist also refers to one who does not conform to, or refuses to be bound by, accepted beliefs, custom or practices.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[stick-in-the-mud](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stick-in-the-mud)*.

> A person who is dull and unadventurous and who resists change.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Such an inhabitant of a stream (cultural or otherwise) surely resists *going with the flow*

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a really bad suggestion seeing as I want to describe myself (and it is obviously very negative)

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that you would like to adjust to the cultural challenges, but find it difficult because of your personality. That sounds like you view your natural inclinations somewhat negatively.

Comment: I understand how it could appear so, but I am really trying to show that I am not going with the flow in a *positive* way as an independent-thinker-kind-of-person and non conformist...

Comment: If you want to emphasize rigidity, you could say *my-way-or-the-highway personality*, but that also has a negative tone. I'm not sure how to make chauvinism sound positive.

Comment: @Idos Sorry, but I didn't see any hint in your question or the comments on it that you wanted to describe an "independent thinker" or "non-conformist". You did say something about not wanting the words "inflexible", "rigid", or "stiff", but that could be because they aren't idiomatic enough; it wasn't clear that it was the _meanings_ of those words that were undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

The verbal "making waves" describes performing an act that doesn't go with the flow, as in "Rob was making waves at the board meeting."  It has a nautical theme and acts as a verb, just like "going with the flow" does.  But it can't be used as an adjective, which seems to be what your sentence is looking for.  If you don't need an exact, plug-in replacement, you could try something like:

"I have had to come to terms with a lot of cultural differences which has been a struggle for my personality, which prefers making waves.

Answer (score 2):

How about -- [Marches to the beat of a different drummer](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/marching+to+the+beat+of+a+different+drummer).

This describes someone who doesn't go along with general march of the masses who listen to the drummer for the masses.  But does a different "march" listening to a different drummer.

And from the [wiktionary entry for *march_to_the_beat_of_a_different_drum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/march_to_the_beat_of_a_different_drum):

> (idiomatic) To do things in one's own way regardless of societal norms and conventional expectations.

Comment: Yes, or the "marches to the beat of his/her own drum" variant.

Answer (score 1):

Psychologists use the term "oppositional" as in "oppositional personality".  It may not be in common use, but I think the meaning is immediately clear.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Other people might not find it immediately clear.

Comment: To me, "going with the flow" means going along with whatever has been presented.  On the other hand, being "oppositional" means being against whatever was presented. As they said in my parent's time "Whatever it is, I'm against it."

Answer (score 1):

[stick to your guns](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stick-to-your-guns)

> to ​continue to have ​your ​beliefs or ​continue with a ​plan of ​action, ​even if other ​people ​disagree with you

Use this expression if the goal is an idiom with a positive connotation. Others, like "stick in the mud" or "going against the grain" have negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

***stubborn-as-a-mule***

is a way of saying someone is extremely [obstinate](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stubborn+as+a+mule) and reluctant to follow others.

This can be shortened to the adjective ***mulish***.